# Red-Black tree insertion infinite loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, red-black-tree

For a class I am in, I am implementing some RB tree methods. When I run my tree on this set of data: 372 245 491 474 440 122 418 125 934 752 in this order, I am getting into my infinite loop when 474 is inserted. I am looking to get a second set of eyes on this because for some reason I am unable to find the error. I've found after debugging several times that the infinite loop is in my insertFixup method. Here is the code I have written:

```
void RBTree ::RBinsert(NodePtr z)
{
   NodePtr y = nil;
   NodePtr x = root;

   // You supply the rest of the code

   while(x != nil) {
      y = x;
      if(z->key < x->key) {
         x = x->left;
      }
      else {
         x = x->right;
      }
   }

   z->p = y;

   if(y == nil) {
      root = z;
   }
   else if(z->key < y->key) {
      y->left = z;
   }
   else {
      y->right = z;
   }

   z->left = nil;
   z->right = nil;

   z->color = 'R';

   insertFixup(z);
}

void RBTree ::insertFixup(NodePtr z)
{
   //this method may not be right yet
   NodePtr y;

   //this is an infinite loop, need to fix
   while (z->p->color == 'R')
   {
      if (z->p == z->p->p->left)
      {
         // You fill this in
         y = z->p->p->right;
         if(y->color == 'R') {
            z->p->color = 'B';
            y->color = 'B';
            z->p->p->color = 'R';
            z = z->p->p;
         }
         else if(z == z->p->right) {
            z = z->p;
            leftRotate(z);
         }
         z->p->color = 'B';
         z->p->p->color = 'R';
         rightRotate(z->p->p);
      }
      else
      {  
         y = z->p->p->left; //uncle
         if(y->color == 'R') {
            z->p->color = 'B';
            y->color = 'B';
            z->p->p->color = 'R';
            z = z->p->p;
         }
         else if(z == z->p->left) {
            z = z->p;
            rightRotate(z); //may need to be left rotate
         }
         z->p->color = 'B';
         z->p->p->color = 'R';
         leftRotate(z->p->p); //may need to be right rotate
      }
   }
   root->color = 'B';
}

void RBTree ::rightRotate(NodePtr x)
{
   NodePtr y = x->left;
   // You write the rest of this
   x->left = y->right;

   if(x->left != nil) {
      x->left->p = x;
   }

   y->p = x->p;

   if(x->p == nil) {
      root = y;
   }
   else if(x == x->p->left) {
      x->p->left = y;
   }
   else {
      x->p->right = y;
   }

   y->right = x;
   x->p = y;
}

void RBTree ::leftRotate(NodePtr x)
{
   //this may not be right yet
   NodePtr y = x->right;
   // You write the rest of this
   x->right = y->left;      
   if(y->left != nil) {     
      y->left->p = x;       
   }
   y->p = x->p;             
   if(x->p == nil) {        
      root = y;             
   }
   else if(x == x->p->left) { 
      x->p->left = y;         
   }
   else {
      x->p->right = y;
   }
   x->left = x;
   x->p = y;
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: What is `nil`?  That is strange to see in C++ code.  Assuming `nullptr`.  Also nice to see what `NodePtr` actually is.  I don't know what 'p' is from looking at your code either.  is it global?  Is it in the struct?  I'd also enable warnings to see what the compiler says.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/CgU2Ex contains a godbolt of it so I know it compiles no warnings.

Comment: Is `p` supposed to be the parent of each node?  If so, your insert is not right.  You use `x` to walk down to an insert location, then set the new node's parent to 'y' , which is the root of the whole tree.  Don't think that is right, but without comments in the code explaining your thinking, it is very hard to guess.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan NodePtr is a typedef for a pointer to a Node in the RB Tree, sorry forgot to mention that. Also, p is the parent.

Comment: Node is struct that contains a self pointer to left, right, parent, then a key and char?  Basically like the godbolt link I posted?

Comment: @tadman I have ran it in a debugger. What I am seeing is that the BST structure holds but when the RB tree properties are violated then I enter an infinite loop in my insertFixup method. It seems to me that when I reset the root pointer in the rotate methods that it is violating the tree property. Both of these tree methods are from pseudocode in the text I am using.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan 'typedef class Node * NodePtr ;' is the code for the NodePtr

Comment: @NathanAnderson *When I run my tree on this set of data: 372 245 491 474 440 122 418 125 934 752* -- Too much test data.  You should be attempting maybe 4 or 5 elements, not 10.  If it doesn't work with 4 or 5, it isn't going to work with 10 elements.

Comment: Do you understand the algorithm that you're implementing? If you do, you should know the correct behavior of the code at each step. When you step through the code, you should then be able to find the first instance where the actual behavior differs from the behavior you expect and that would be the buggy part. You might want to use a simpler example so that you can easily figure out exactly what's supposed to happen at every point. Draw a diagram if it helps.

Comment: The easiest way to debug such a thing is to put assertions of the invariant of the RB-Tree. You need to understand where the invariant is being broken. When you will know that, understanding the error should be much simpler.